# How do I file one Pull Request per Commit after making multiple Commits?

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request, cherry-pick

I've been working on a project and made good progress on several tasks.

I have been careful enough to keep all my changes for each task on their own individual commits.

Now, I want to issue pull requests for each commit individually, so there is only one commit per pull request.

What is the best way to go about this?

I've read it involves branches and cherry pick? I'd appreciate a tutorial, walkthrough or process flow.

Ideally I'd like to do this using a GUI, but first I'd appreciate the background of how and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is also to use separate branch for each pull request & `cherry-pick` your commits to those separate branches.

For that I will give you the process with this below example,
You have your `master` branch without any of your feature commits & you have your `Dev` branch with all of your commits A,B,C,D

```
master

Dev => A,B,C,D
```

First you have to checkout to your `master` branch

```
git checkout master
```

Then create `FEATURE-A` branch from `master`

```
git checkout -b FEATURE-A
```

Then `cherry-pick` your commit A to `FEATURE-A` branch

```
git cherry-pick A #A is the hash value of your commit. Eg- 2f8b782
```

Now you have your `FEATURE-A` branch with only the commit A. So now you can `push` your `FEATURE-A` branch to `origin` & create the `pull request`

```
git push origin FEATURE-A
```

And repeat the same process to other commits as well.

Hope you understand what I'm trying to tell you. I tried my best to keep this as simple as possible. If you have any question, comment below

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted—thanks! I have just gone through the process and it worked perfectly. 

GitHub Desktop doesn't allow cherry-pick so I had to use an alternative client. 

GitUp and SourceTree both do and I was able to do it in both (I prefer the SourceTree UI fwiw). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `git format-patch` and `git am` pair command to do this.

```
mkdir patches
git checkout Dev
git format-patch -o patches master
```

By these three command your patches with one files for one commit will be saved in patches folder.

Then create new branch from master branch and apply all those patches

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b FEATURE-A
git am patches
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure I've seen that option in any GUI. Why would you choose format-patch&&am over branches&&cherry-pick?

Comment: @MattSephton, Instead of do it one-by-one by cherry-pick, I like to do it in batch mode.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the batch aspect in your answer above?

Comment: @MattSephton, `git format-patch` will create patch files for each commit and save all those to `patches` folder. when you specify  `patches` folder to `git am`, git will apply patch files in that folder one by one automatically.

Comment: great! I'm going to try that next time